# Make arraylist parcelable in my code?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, parcelable

Can anybody help me making the *arraylist* `final ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();`
Parcelable in my code so I can access it in methods in both **fragment** **a** and **b**

**- Fragment a code:**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
// Store instance variables
private String title;
private int page;

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static SecondFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    SecondFragment fragmentSecond = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentSecond.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentSecond;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    TextView tvLabel2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Alle Objekte hier einfügen (wie textview tvavel2)

    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view) {



            if (editText3.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You did not enter a Valid Item ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            else if (editText2.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You did not enter a Valid Quantitiy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;

            }

            else {

                String nomen = (editText3.getText().toString());
                float number = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());

                entries.add(new PieEntry(number, nomen));

                editText3.setText("");
                editText2.setText("");
                editText3.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

- **Fragment b code:**

  ```
  public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
  private String title;
  private int page;



  public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
  FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putInt("someInt", page);
  args.putString("someTitle", title);
  fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
  return fragmentFirst;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
  title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
  }


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
      EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
  final PieChart piechart = (PieChart) view.findViewById(R.id.piechart);
  final Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

  new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {


      }
  };

  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick (View view) {
          getResources().getColor(R.color.violp);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.bluep);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.redp);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.greenp);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.yellowp);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.orangep);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.lightbluep);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.purplep);
          getResources().getColor(R.color.darkredp);
          PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
          set.setColors(new int[]{R.color.bluep, R.color.greenp, R.color.violp, R.color.redp, R.color.yellowp, R.color.orangep, R.color.lightbluep, R.color.purplep, R.color.darkredp}, getActivity());
          PieData datax = new PieData(set);
          piechart.setData(datax);
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (R.string.loading),
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          piechart.setNoDataText(String.valueOf(R.string.nodata));
          piechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
          piechart.animateX(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInExpo);
          piechart.animateY(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInExpo);



          }



      });






  return view;
  }
  ```

I have tried a number of options so far but I could not get the programm to run.
Any help is apprediated.
**Thanks!**

Comment: How can i do this? :) Please be specific, i am new to coding :D

Answer (score 1):

In order to transfer data, we need to parcel it or serialize it. Android OS by default promoting Parcelable instead to Serialization. Serialization is a java concept. In your case, you need to create the "PieEntry" class as Parcelable. For that, you need to implement the Parcelable interface in your model.

Check below implementation.

```
package com.cludprinting.mysample;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by nithinjith.pp on 05-01-2017.
 * Implement Parcelable in PieEntry.
 * 
 */

public class PieEntry implements Parcelable {

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<PieEntry> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PieEntry>() {
        @Override
        public PieEntry createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new PieEntry(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PieEntry[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PieEntry[size];
        }
    };

    // These are sample instance variables
   // Add your own instance variable
    private String mName;
    private String mDOB;
    private int mAge;

    public PieEntry(Parcel parcel) {
        this.mName = parcel.readString();
        this.mDOB = parcel.readString();
        this.mAge = parcel.readInt();
    }


    public int getmAge() {
        return mAge;
    }

    public void setmAge(int mAge) {
        this.mAge = mAge;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.mName);
        dest.writeString(this.mDOB);
        dest.writeInt(this.mAge);
    }

    public String getmDOB() {
        return mDOB;
    }

    public void setmDOB(String mDOB) {
        this.mDOB = mDOB;
    }

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setmName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }
}
```

The instance variable and access methods may change based on your implemenaton.